# ffmpegでフレームの生データを出力する方法

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpegで動画の静止画を出力するには下記のような方法で出力できますが、

$ ffmpeg -i 元動画.avi -ss 144 -t 148 -r 24 -f image2 %06d.jpg

I,B, Pフレームの生データを出力する方法はないでしょうか？

Comment: "生データ"というのはデコード前のビットストリームという意味でしょうか？また"元動画.avi"の映像コーデックは何を使っているのでしょう？

Comment: そうです。ビットストリームのことです。元動画のコーデックはmpeg2です。

Answer (score 2):

> ビットストリームのことです。元動画のコーデックはmpeg2です。

単純にMPEG-2 Videoビットストリームを抽出するだけであれば、下記コマンドで実現可能です：

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -c:v copy -f mpeg2video output.mp2v
```

**注意：** AVIコンテナはその仕様上、Bフレームを含むMPEG-2 Videoストリームを"正しく"格納できません。"Packed B-frame"とよばれる回避策も考えられてはいますが、正しく取り扱えるか否かは動画プレイヤー次第です。MPEG-2 Videoを取り扱う場合、AVIコンテナの利用は避けたほうがよいです。

---

> I,B, Pフレームの生データを出力する方法はないでしょうか？

おそらく、ツールとしてのFFmpegにそのような機能はありません。

- （cubickさん回答でも言及されている）Video Filterは、デコード後の映像フレームに対するフィルタ処理になります。
- ビットストリームを取り扱う BitStream Filter(bsf) という仕組みも存在しますが、所望されるようなフィルタは提供されません。

また、仮に"P/Bフレームのみ"データを取り出せたとしても、そのデータのみでは正しく映像デコードを行えません。MPEG-2デコーダや解析ツールを開発されているなら話は別ですが、そうでなければ、Iフレームを含まないデータには全く使い道がありません。
なお、"Iフレームのみのデータ"は完結して映像デコード可能なので、ギリギリ意味があるかもしれません。

Comment: yohjpさん、cubickさん。ありがとうございました。実は、デコーダにフレームデータを渡す部分の処理を作成しており、mpeg2のデータからフレームデータを取得して動画再生させるところまでは出来たのですが、ところどころにゴミデータが入ってしまい、ffmpegの処理と比較できないかと

Comment: (続き)考えました。  幸い、<http://proc-cpuinfo.fixstars.com/2017/08/ffmpeg-api-decode/>を参考にして、av_read_frame()後のpacket.buf->dataからフレームデータを取得することができました。

Comment: ついでで申し訳ないですが、IフレームのみのBitStreamをデコードすることは可能でしょうか？

Comment: 原理的にはデコード可能です。が、実際のMPEG-2 Video BitstreamはGOP(group of pictures)を最小単位とする構造化されたデータのため、純粋に「Iフレーム部分のBitstreamデータ」だけを切り‌​出しても正常デコードできるとは限りません。see https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/Multimedia/node262.html

Comment: yohjpさん、ありがとうございます。Iフレーム部分のBitStreamデータに対してのデコードはあきらめます。

Answer (score 0):

`select`フィルタで出力が可能なようです。

> - Bフレーム
>     `-vf select=eq(pict_type\,B)`
> - Pフレーム
>     `-vf select=eq(pict_type\,P)`
> - Iフレーム
>     `-vf select=eq(pict_type\,I)` or `-skip_frame nokey`

参考：
[【ffmpeg】動画から特定フレームを画像で出力する方法 : ニコニコ動画研究所](http://looooooooop.blog35.fc2.com/blog-entry-1021.html#bpi)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。指摘いただいた内容でjpgやpngの画像は保存できました。ただ、欲しいデータは元のデータのバイナリです。mpeg2でいうとPESの中身が欲しいです。